# Android x86 Repo Init - Permission Denied

Tags: linux, permissions, android-x86

I'm trying to init a repo to download the android-x86 source. I've done it before and had no problems.

Today it keeps saying permission denied, i've reset the permissions and owner with `chmod` and `chown`, no dice.

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I've tried with and without sudo. I am the only user of the PC but it keeps refusing to init the repo. Is there a way round this without a full reinstall of ubuntu? The permissions system makes no sense to me. I am the only user, I own the folders, I own the files, permissions are set to allow read, write, execute and still I get permission denied errors.

Please help.

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you are doing. What command says that? Where are you running that command, etc?

Comment: The command I am running is the standard repo init from the android-x86 website. repo init -u git://git.osdn.net/gitroot/android-x86/manifest -b pie.